# Loading django custom tags inside a Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I'm currently loading some HTML to a template using some Javascript and the HTML is stored inside a django template tag. I have a custom template tag from a separate app which generates an SVG image file.

Here is my template tag:

```
{% icon "test-icon" %}
```

Here is the variable the stores the HTML, which i wish to load the tag into:

```
var imageLeft = "$('<div class="testing"></div>')"
```

I've tried the obvious:

```
var imageLeft = "$('<div class="testing">{% load "test-icon" %}</div>')"
```

This is new to me so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `var imageLeft = $('<div class="testing">{% load "test-icon" %}</div>')`
is not working ?

Comment: No i seem to get 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL' in the console. Think it could possible be complaining about this line - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your tag generates output that terminates the string you're trying to insert it into.

Try placing it in a hidden tag on your page:

```
<div id="cached-icon" hidden>{% icon "test-icon" %}</div>
```

then fetch it from javascript

```
var imageLeft = $('<div class="testing"/>').append($('#cached-icon').show());
```